# Assign to a component the event of another component at runtime

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

Is it possible to assign to a component the event of another component at runtime?

It would be to do what is done at design-time, as shown in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Object Inspector only allows you to assign event handlers that are declared as `published` on the Form itself. You can't assign a component method as an event handler to another component *at design-time*.

At *runtime*, however, you can assign *any* object method as an event handler of *any* object event, provided that the method is compatible with the event.

For example:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent *Owner)
{
    Rectangle3->OnPaint = this->Rectangle1Paint;
    // or:
    Rectangle3->OnPaint = Rectangle1->OnPaint;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Rectangle1Paint(TObject* Sender, TCanvas* Canvas, const TRectF &ARect)
{
    // use Sender to know which Rectangle is being drawn...
}
```